# cURL not fetching page as expected - 404 error

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the following code to fetch search results from soundcloud.com. Although the URL pulls up search results from the browser, echoing the cURL result pulls up a 404/"page not found" error.

In case this helps -> If I comment out the useragent line, I can display other URLs from that domain, but not the search results. The pages I can see state "you are using an older version of Sound Cloud".

```
<?php

    $url = 'https://soundcloud.com/search?q=a';

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13',
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url));

    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $resp;
    echo curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Comment: I don't see why you get 404, though the URL will never return a search result since the search result is loaded via ajax from the page. you may want to take a look at SoundCloud API instead http://developers.soundcloud.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **SoundCloud API** for search everything.

I captured soundcloud search packet and take a look:

[image]

soundcloud official website search is using ajax and **SoundCloud API**. so, you can't get the search result using your code. (it is possible when you use PhantomJS, but it is very inefficiency)

Please visit the [SoundCloud API Documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/) page. create your own app and generate api token to access the soundcloud search api.

add: this link is very helpful for you: https://github.com/davidmh/CakePHP-SoundcloudSearch-Plugin/blob/master/Controller/Component/SoundcloudSearchComponent.php